# How To Associate A PIP to An Azure Front Door

Tags: azure, networking, azure-front-door

I have created some front doors all configured correctly and route to my backend pools succesfuly but now I need to create DNS entries to route specifc domain/urls to this front door. I can't seem to find an auto generated PIP for the front door. So I was trying to find a way to generate an association from a new PIP I created and the front door so I can create a DNS record for the site.

Comment: There is a much easier way to do this. Just use an application gateway. Has almost all the same features of front door and can be configured alot more thand fronr door

Comment: Why are you talking to yourself!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much easier way to do this. Just use an application gateway. Has almost all the same features of front door and can be configured alot more than fronr door

Comment: AG doesn't have things like IP rate limiting, and you have to buy the wildcard cert for $299

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to configure custom domains for the front door then create each routing rule for each frontend custom domain host. Besides apex domains and subdomains, you can also map a [wildcard domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-wildcard-domain) to your front-end hosts or custom domains for your Azure Front Door profile.

Front Door doesn't expose the frontend IP address associated with your Front Door profile. So you can't map your apex domain to an IP address if your intent is to onboard it to Azure Front Door. This problem can be resolved by using [alias records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain#create-an-alias-record-for-zone-apex) in Azure DNS.

References:

- [Tutorial: Add a custom domain to your Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain)
- [Onboard a root or apex domain on your Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain)